# How to get all items in a search scope in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I thought I could just do something like this:

```
        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
        oQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='MyScope'";
        SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
```

but it is pulling back a bunch of stuff that is not in the scope.  Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing SPQuery, which a list querying class, based on CAML, and the search API. Take a look into FullTextSqlQuery, which is the class you really should work with.

Comment: Hmm, well i'm trying to update one of the fields on all the items i found.  I thought I could only do that if it was a list item? A full text query would return a ResultTable which won't allow me to update anything, right? (I'm brand new to SP so please let me know if I am way off base on any of the above).

Comment: This is correct, but then you can use the data you receive to retrieve the item by ID and update it.